# How do you solve for bounds when performing trig substitution and knowing solving the trig functions yields multiple correct values of $\theta$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

Suppose that f is a nonnegative continuous function on [a,b] and R is the region in the xy plane between the graph of f and the x axis on [a,b].  Let D be the solid region generated by revolving R about the x-axis (see figure below). Show that the formula

$\int \int_D \int1 dV = \int_a^b\pi(f(x)^2dx$

I completed this problem and got the right answer, but my question concerns the bounds when performing the trig sub:

$\int_a^b \int_{-f(x)}^{f(x)}2 \sqrt{f(x)^2-y^2} dy dx$

Notice that $\sqrt{f(x)^2-y^2} = f sin(\theta)$ and $y=fcos(\theta)$ so $dy = -f sin(\theta)d\theta$. Also observe solving for $\theta(y)=cos^{-1}(\frac{y}{f})$.  This implies $\theta(-f(x))=cos^{-1}(-1)$ and $\theta(f(x))=cos^{-1}(1)$

For  $\theta(-f(x))$ I chose $\pi$ and for $\theta(f(x))$ I chose $2\pi$. However, when I worked the problem out, my answer was off by a negative sign (i.e. I got the negative volume of D).

But when I choose $- \pi$ for $\theta(-f(x))$ and $0$ for $\theta(f(x))$ I got the right answer.

So I'm wondering why I get the wrong answer even though I satisfy  $\theta(-f(x))=cos^{-1}(-1)$ and $\theta(f(x))=cos^{-1}(1)$ for some $\theta$ and not other $\theta$?

[image]